# Firestore custom indexing not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my firestore database, I have a collection named `states`, I have added `stateId` and `stateName` in indexes manually. when I tried to access the collection using cloud functions, it reports a crash stating that the query requires indexing and shows/generated a link to add index. But when I copy_pasted the link, it is not showing `stateName` in the indexing field , I am ordering based on `stateName`. Here is the screenshot of manually indexed collections

[image]

this is my code to get the list of states

```
exports.getStates = functions.https.onRequest((request, response)=>{
    const db = admin.firEDIT !estore();
    const countryId = request.body['countryId'];
    return db.collection("states").where("countryId","==",countryId).where("isDeleted","==","0")
    .select("stateId","stateName").orderBy("stateName")
    .get().then(snapshot=>{
        const states =[];
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc=>{
            states.push(doc.data());
        });
        return response.status(200).json(states);
    });
});
```

This is the error shown in firebase console logs

```
Error: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/functionstest-54bd9/database/firestore/indexes?create_index=EglkaXN0cmljdHMaDQoJaXNEZWxldGVkEAIaCwoHc3RhdGVJZBACGhAKDGRpc3RyaWN0TmFtZRACGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAI
    at ClientReadableStream._emitStatusIfDone (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:255:19)
    at ClientReadableStream._receiveStatus (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:233:8)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:705:12
```

What is wrong with my code? How can I make the ordering based on `stateName` work?

**UPDATE 1**

I used the link provided in the firebase console logs and then the `stateName` is also listed in indexing fields and the collection is now indexed and it is working as intended. Here are my doubts

1. Why it didn't show the `stateName` at first and is shown in second try?
2. Why manual indexing is not working?

Comment: Please edit you question to be specific about this crash.  Is there an error message?

Comment: i will post the firebase console log

Comment: Did you happen to notice any messages in the console stating that it may take some time to create the index?  How long did you wait?

Comment: No i didn't notice any messages and i tried running the cloud function after 2-3 minutes, it think, because i was deploying another 2 functions while it was building the indexes and i checked the console to make sure that the indexing is finished

Answer (score 5):

Do not added manually,  Just follow the link, it will land you on console.firebase. and automatically create a INDEX for you. and then it will work.